# Create a class from string and execute a method on it

Tags: c#

I have two separate/distinct implementation of "Product" sync. They ought to be ran based on sync "Direction" setting.

So, the classes are stored like this on my project:

[image]

Both classes identical constructor and a common public "Run" method - which initiates the sync process.

Currently, I am creating an instance of either of these class and executing the "Run" method like this:

```
private void RunProductSync()
{
    if (_organisation.Data.Settings.Sync.Direction == "IN")
    {
        // Sync IN
        (new Sync.IN.Product(
            _icApi, 
            _icLogger)).Run();
    }
    else if (_organisation.Data.Settings.Sync.Direction == "OUT")
    {
        // Sync OUT
        (new Sync.OUT.Product(
            _icApi,
            _icLogger)).Run();
    }
}
```

This approach works, but I want to implement a dynamic class instantiation with method invocation.

One approach I tried uses the `Activator.CreateInstance` feature of .NET, which looks like this:

```
var sync = Activator.CreateInstance(
    Type.GetType(
        string.Format("Sync.{0}.Product",
            _organisation.Data.Settings.Sync.Direction)));
```

However, to be able to execute the `Run` method on this object, I still have to do this:

```
if (_organisation.Data.Settings.Sync.Direction == "IN") {
    (sync AS Sync.IN.Product).Run();
} else if (_organisation.Data.Settings.Sync.Direction == "OUT") {
    (sync AS Sync.OUT.Product).Run();
}
```

This is still not any better than what I started with. Is there a better way to do this?

---

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @[theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6888189/theo) - I have the following working great for me:

**ISync.cs**

```
interface ISync
{
    void Run();
}
```

**Sync/IN/Product.cs** & **Sync/OUT/Product.cs**

```
public class Product : ISync
{
    public Product(Api _icApi, Logger _icLogger)
    { ... }

    public void Run()
    { ... }
}
```

Class is dynamically instantiated & method executed like this:

```
((ISync)Activator.CreateInstance(
    Type.GetType(
        string.Format("Sync.{0}.Product",
            _organisation.Data.Settings.Sync.Direction)),
    _icApi,
    _icLogger).Run();
```

Comment: Code to an interface?

Comment: I don't see any problems with your initial approach

Comment: This smells of astro-engineering. Think about you/anyone else who has to maintain this code in 6 month's time. Which approach would they prefer?

Comment: Definitely sounds like an interface issue to me. Reflection is a possibility, but oftentimes there's a simpler way.

Comment: an abstract factory seems like an overkill if there are only 2 classes... Your first approach seems easy enough to maintain.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I had asked the question because I actually have 2 more "sync types" to implement (one for Stock and one for Orders).

Comment: If you want to get rid of the "duplicate code" you could declare `Run()` in a base class that they both inherit from, then only cast to the base class once no matter which one it is and call Run on it: `BaseClass sync = Activator.CreateInstance ... sync.Run()`. You could use `dynamic`: `dynamic sync = Activator.CreateInstance ... sync.Run()`, but you lose all compile time type checking. Just saying what's out there, it appears that an interface is the preferred solution to your request.

Comment: @Latheesan If you have a couple of more sync classes as well, a factory of some sort would work well.  The factory would take a direction parameter such as 'In', 'Out', etc and return an instance of `IProduct`

Comment: Come to think of it, I've never had two classes share the exact same name, I don't like that at all. That would be my first concern.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ the classes exists in different namespace.

Comment: @Latheesan - still, they're being used in the same context. It feels like the crooks of the issue lie at the way you're attempting to reuse them which then causes you to have to write code that distinguishes between the two. Maybe direction should be a property on the class? Or, as others have suggested, employ an interface - this is a textbook example of where you should do the latter really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding an IProduct interface to both classes:

```
public interface IProduct
{
    void Run();
}
```

then you can do this:

```
var sync = (IProduct)Activator.CreateInstance(
    Type.GetType(
        string.Format("Sync.{0}.Product",
            _organisation.Data.Settings.Sync.Direction)));

sync.Run();
```

Comment: I like this approach, simple enough to maintain. Is it possible to pass the two parameters to the class (as per my initial approach) using this `Activator.CreateInstance` ?

Comment: Yup. You could/should extend the interface to include all comonality between the products so it can be used generically. As some have pointed out if there are common implementations between the two classes, use a base class as well as or instead of an interface.